# should I use self join

Tags: python, mysql, sql, join, select

I have a table (test_data) in mysql  . 
Sample data with column names is as below

```
date    Company_name    company_id  Company_name    company_id  code    
01-04-2020  XYZ Ltd     001          ABC Ltd            002     80002   
01-04-2020  ABC Ltd     002          XYZ Ltd            001     80002   
01-04-2020  ABC Ltd     002          DEF Ltd            003     80002   
01-04-2020  DEF Ltd     003          ABC Ltd            002     80002   
01-04-2020  PQ Ltd      004          ABC Ltd            002     80002
```

Need to filter only those having both way handshake between them on a particular date. For example on 01-04-2020 the result should be

```
date    Company_name    company_id  Company_name    company_id  
01-04-2020  XYZ Ltd     001         ABC Ltd        002  
01-04-2020  ABC Ltd     002         XYZ Ltd        001  
01-04-2020  ABC Ltd     002         DEF Ltd        003     
01-04-2020  DEF Ltd     003         ABC Ltd        002
```

Have used self join but result gives more rows than required

Comment: Please don't ask us to do your (home)work. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table.

Answer (score 1):

With EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where date = t.date and company_id1 = t.company_id2 and company_id2 = t.company_id1
)
```

I assume that the column names are something like: `company_id1` and `company_id2` because you can't have 2 columns with the same name in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. That with the self join was a good idea.

But i had to rename the colum names because identical doesn't work

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  `date` VARCHAR(10),
  `Company_name1` VARCHAR(19),
  `company_id1` VARCHAR(20),
  `Company_name` VARCHAR(20),
  `company_id` VARCHAR(10),
  `code` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO table1
  (`date`, `Company_name1`, `company_id1`, `Company_name`, `company_id`, `code`)
VALUES
  ('01-04-2020', 'XYZ Ltd', 'AAAPL1234T', 'ABC Ltd', 'BBBLY1234K', '80002'),
  ('01-04-2020', 'ABC Ltd', 'BBBLY1234K', 'XYZ Ltd', 'AAAPL1234T', '80002'),
  ('01-04-2020', 'ABC Ltd', 'BBBLY1234K',  'DEF Ltd', 'EFGHI1234Y', '80002'),
  ('01-04-2020', 'DEF Ltd',  'EFGHI1234Y', 'ABC Ltd', 'BBBLY1234K', '80002'),
  ('01-04-2020', 'PQ Ltd', 'HIJKL1234T', 'ABC Ltd' , 'BBBLY1234K', '80002');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROm table1 t1 INNER JOIN
table1 t2 ON t1.Company_name1 = t2.Company_name AND t1.company_id1 = t2.company_id

| date       | Company_name1 | company_id1 | Company_name | company_id | code  |
| ---------- | ------------- | ----------- | ------------ | ---------- | ----- |
| 01-04-2020 | ABC Ltd       | BBBLY1234K  | XYZ Ltd      | AAAPL1234T | 80002 |
| 01-04-2020 | XYZ Ltd       | AAAPL1234T  | ABC Ltd      | BBBLY1234K | 80002 |
| 01-04-2020 | DEF Ltd       | EFGHI1234Y  | ABC Ltd      | BBBLY1234K | 80002 |
| 01-04-2020 | ABC Ltd       | BBBLY1234K  | DEF Ltd      | EFGHI1234Y | 80002 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUqVKNZy96RjR7hTk3md7o/2)